# iptables rule cannot be added

Tags: iptables

Is there anything wrong with these rules? They cannot be added to iptables, no error but they just don't show up in `iptables -vnL`

```
iptables  -I FORWARD 1 -s 1.2.3.4 -p udp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 --connlimit-mask 24 -j DROP

iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 1.2.3.4 -p udp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 -j DROP

iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 1.2.3.4/24 -p udp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 --connlimit-mask 24 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
iptables -vnL FORWARD
```